# paragraph to vector spacy

Tags: nltk, spacy, word-embedding

I have a input test string which is multiline

```
input_text = "this is my example text !!. nothing serious about it."
```

I want to create an embedding of fixed length using `spacy`. How this can be be done? Is there any wrapper function where I can define arguments like `input_text`, `embedding length` and `ensemble method`. Also will stop words, special characters need to be removed or they will be removed by wrapper method, if this exists
.
Thanks